# tracing back recursive calls

Tags: arrays, recursion

I am new to recursion and trying to understand how it works and trying to trace it how it is approaching to find answers.This below written code finds out the last index of the searched number in the integer array ,for instance `in[4]={1,2,3,2}` and the searched number in this array is `2` .
the answer for this question is `3` as it is the last index.Now I will try to write how this code does it.The `in[]` is the input array and stin is the starting integer and the number that is to be found is `num`.

1. at line int ans  lastINdex(in,stin+1,size,num) the function is called recursively to its base case that is when its size becomes stin==siz.then its value is returned to the function that has called it .my question is how this funtion will reach the line after the recursive statement. please provide an explaination of this code.

   `int lindex(int in[], int stin, int num){
     int size=strlen(in);
     if(stin == size){
       return -1;
     }
     int ans = lastIndex(in, stin + 1, num);
     if(ans != -1){
       return ans;
     }else{
       if(in[stin] == num){
         return stin;
       }else{
         return -1;
       }
     }
   }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implementation will reach the line after the recursive call by returning from it. If one is unfamiliar with recursion, it might get some time to get used to it. If you are able to use a debugger, I strongly recommend to experiment with it and examine the call stack and local variable values. However, the sequence of recursive calls can be expanded as follows, using your example, using a pseudocodish notation, where values are inserted.

```
1. call lindex({1,2,3,4}, 0, 2):
   int size=strlen(in); // assigns 4
   if(0 == 4){          // condition is false
   }
   int ans = lastIndex({1,2,3,4}, 1, 2); // assigns 3, as we see below
   if(3 != -1){         // condition is true
       return 3;
   }

2. call lindex({1,2,3,4}, 1, 2):
   int size=strlen(in); // assigns 4
   if(1 == 4){          // condition is false
   }
   int ans = lastIndex({1,2,3,4}, 2, 2); // assigns 3, as we see below
   if(3 != -1){         // condition is true
       return 3;
   }

3. call lindex({1,2,3,4}, 2, 2):
   int size=strlen(in); // assigns 4
   if(2 == 4){          // condition is false
   }
   int ans = lastIndex({1,2,3,4}, 3, 2); // assigns 3, as we see below
   if(3 != -1){         // condition is true
       return 3;
   }

4. call lindex({1,2,3,4}, 3, 2):
   int size=strlen(in); // assigns 4
   if(3 == 4){          // condition is false
   }
   int ans = lastIndex({1,2,3,4}, 4, 2); // assigns -1, as we see below
   if(-1 != -1){         // condition is false
   }else{
       if(in[3] == 2){   // condition is true
       return 3;
   }

5. call lindex({1,2,3,4}, 4, 2):
   int size=strlen(in); // assigns 4
   if(4 == 4){          // condition is true
       return -1;
   }
```

The implementation becomes more accessible if we discuss the semantics of the individual steps. First, it is checked whether the start index points behzind the array, in which case the desired number cannot be found and -1 is returned. otherwise, we seek the number to find in the tail of the array. If it can be found there, we return the index found in the recursive call. Otherwise, we test the current position for equality with the desired number to find, as it does not occur in the tail of the array. In total, this returns the index of the rightmost occurence of the searched number (if it is contained at all).

The 'stepping back' by returning from the recursive calls is done via the call stack; each recursive call has its own set of local variables.

Comment: `int ans = lastIndex({1,2,3,4}, 1, 2); // assigns 3, as we see below` how this steps return 3

Comment: @bogor How the call returns 3 is described in step 3, where the recursion is followed further.